# Definition of custom class and different methods

Tags: python

I have below definition:

```
def fun1(x) :
    return x + 2

class my_class :
    def fun1(x) :
        return x + 22
    def fun2(x) :
        return fun1(x) + 33

print(my_class.fun2(10))
```

However this returns 45, whereas I am expecting 65 (10 + 22 + 33).

Where am I making a mistake?

Comment: `fun1` refers to the _function_, not the instance method `self.fun1`.

Comment: yep, do self.fun1

Comment: I tried with `self.fun1(x) + 33` - but it is returning error `NameError: name 'self' is not defined`

Comment: You also need to actually take `self` as a parameter of the instance methods

Comment: Alternatively, you can just use `my_class.fun1` not `self.fun1`

Comment: @Lecdi could you please elaborate your comment `You also need to actually take self as a parameter of the instance methods`

Comment: I strongly recommend that you look at some Python tutorial, especially the part about classes. See for example [the classes chapter from the official tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be a way out but, not a recommended style:

```
class my_class:
    def fun1(x) :
        return x + 22
    def fun2(x) :
        return my_class.fun1(x) + 33
my_class.fun2(10)
```

Another unorthodox way:

```
class my_class:
    def fun1(x) :
        return x + 22
    @classmethod
    def fun2(cls,x) :
        return cls.fun1(x) + 33
my_class.fun2(10)
```

The best way I can think of:

```
def fun1(x) :
    return x + 2

class my_class :
    def fun1(self,x) : 
        return x + 22
    def fun2(self,x) :
        return self.fun1(x) + 33 #refering to instance method self.fun1

print(my_class().fun2(10)) # my_class() is a object
```